# customization of edit text and input type in android

Tags: android

I had customized edit text with floating label and  i write a method to set input type which is working but for last edit text its showing number keyboard instead of normal keyboard take alook at my code

```
 private void setFloatInputType(int inputType) {

    if(inputType==16) {
        input.setFocusable(false);
        input.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);
        input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setDatePicker();
            }
        });
    }
        else
    if(inputType==0) {

       input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
       // input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
        Log.d("INput TYp3", "" + input.getInputType());
    }
    else
        input.setInputType(inputType);

I had debug the code it showsthat for third text field input type is set to
```

normal keyboard but os is popup numberic keyboard.

any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

with

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```